# Solving $0=\sum_{T=0}^{L}(2u^2A-2Ou)$ for $O$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know this seems like a very simple question, but I haven't been able to find anything online regarding the answer to this.

Even WolframAlpha, which I usually use when I don't know the answer to a problem like this, fails to find a result.

I need to rearrange for O (and then fully simplify): $$0=\sum_{T=0}^{L}(2u^2A-2Ou)$$

Where $u$ is an expression that includes $T$, and $A,O, L$ are all variables

So far, my working includes:

$$0=\sum_{T=0}^{L}(2u^2A)-\sum_{T=0}^{L}(2Ou)$$

$$\sum_{T=0}^{L}(2Ou)=\sum_{T=0}^{L}(2u^2A)$$

$$2O\sum_{T=0}^{L}(u)=2A\sum_{T=0}^{L}(u^2)$$

$$O=\frac{A\sum_{T=0}^{L}(u^2)}{\sum_{T=0}^{L}(u)}$$

If this is all correct, can this final expression of $\frac{A\sum_{T=0}^{L}(u^2)}{\sum_{T=0}^{L}(u)}$ be simplified further?

Simplifying to $A\sum_{T=0}^{L}(u)$ doesn't seem to work

Comment: Your last equation cannot be simplified further without strong assumptions about the $u$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In which case, do you know what scenarios would allow it to be simplified further and in what situations is that it's most simplified form?

Comment: Only extreme assumptions (such as $u = 0$).  By the way, why do you want to simplify it further?  And why do you even expect that it can?

Comment: I haven't had much experience with $∑$ before, and it seemed as if there would be a way to write it in a single ∑ because $u^2/u = u$, and I thought it might apply to this @DavidG.Stork . Thanks for your help!

Comment: You certainly can*not* "simplify" the ratio of the sums by cancelling a factor of $u$.  Certainly *not*!  Just write out a small simple example to convince yourself.

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld Where are the indices?

Comment: @callculus What do you mean by indices? The exponent?

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld For instance the arithmetic mean is calculated as $\overline x=\frac1n\cdot \sum\limits_{{\color{red}i}=1}^n x_{{\color{red}i}}$ Usually you have an index when a sigma sign is involved.

Comment: @callculus Ah yes, the index ($T$) is part of the expression $u$

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld Then make an edit which shows the right expression.

Comment: @callculus I haven't got a specific expression for $u$, I was just curious if it could be simplified further, especially since Wolfram Alpha didn't work whenever I tried it so thanks for your help :)